# Extend @Page Page-margin Box Dimensions in the footer

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a disclaimer to the bottom of a HTML page that will be converted into a PDF document. This document needs to have a block text disclaimer on each page in the same spot.

My question is there a way to extend the size of @Page margin boxes similar to this, or be able to span two or more so that I can fit all of the needed block text.

```
@page {
   @bottom-right-corner {
      content: 'Block Text...';
      text-align: center;
      width: 1000px;
   }
}
```

A reference of the @ rules I'm trying to use.

[Margin Box Examples](https://www.quackit.com/css/at-rules/css_right-bottom_at-rule.cfm)

[Margin Box Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#margin-boxes)

Comment: @florianh No I wasn't able to, sorry.